# Multiple event maps and helpers for multiple text inputs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've got this helper and event map with a Session. The event is listening for a button click then grabs the input text from the input field. Then it sets the Session. The helper gets the Session and does a find() on the collection for CampYear (one of the collection fields).

```
Session.setDefault('keyCampYear', '');

Template.camp.helpers({
  'Query': function () {
    var cy = Session.get('keyCampYear');
    return Programs.find({CampYear: cy}).fetch();
  }
});

Template.query.events({
  'click #camp-year-button': function(event) {
    var campYearTemp = document.getElementById('camp-year').value;
    Session.set('keyCampYear', campYearTemp);
  }
});
```

The output is set up with a spacebars {{#each}} to present a table:

```
<tbody>
    {{#each Query}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{Fname}}</td>
        <td>{{Lname}}</td>
        <td>{{CampYear}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

This works as expected. I now need to add another text field and button to query the database for a different field, and output to the same spacebars {{#each}}.  But I'm not able to get it working. Adding another event map, Session and helper doesn't seem to work. Is there a way I can get another input field with its button to search for a different field in the collection and output on the same spacebars {{#each}}?

NON-WORKING CODE BELOW:

Add text box and button:

```
<input type="text" id="donate">
<button id="donate-button">GO</button>
```

Add new event map, helper and Session:

```
Session.setDefault('keyDonate', '');

Template.camp.helpers({
  'Query': function () {
    var don = Session.get('keyDonate');
    return Programs.find({DONATE: don}).fetch();
  }
});

Template.query.events({
  'click #donate-button': function() {
    var donateTemp = parseInt(document.getElementById('donate').value, 10);
    Session.set('keyDonate', donateTemp);
}
});
```

What ends up happening is that the entire Mongo collection loads in the browser by default, without the user clicking either button. The first button and text box are inoperable, the newly created button and text box work, but very sluggishly.

Comment: You need to show the non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution. I'm not familiar with Meteor enough to know that this is THE solution, but here's what I did. First, to prevent the entire collection from loading on the page, both Sessions had to be set to a default of undefined:

```
Session.setDefault('key', undefined);
```

Rather than:

```
Session.setDefault('key', '');
```

I could default one Session like this with a '' value and it didn't seem to mind, with two set like this, things went haywire. The next change was to add another Spacebars {{#each}} inside the table just below the first one.

```
{{#each Query}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{Fname}}</td>
    <td>{{Lname}}</td>
    <td>{{CampYear}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
{{#each Query2}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{Fname}}</td>
        <td>{{Lname}}</td>
        <td>{{CampYear}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Each helper now needs to link to the appropriate {{#each}}. The third part was that I was forced to set one Session back to undefined while setting the other to prevent stacking the tables on top of each other.

```
Template.query.events({
  'click #donate-button': function() {
    var donateTemp = parseInt(document.getElementById('donate').value, 10);
  Session.set('keyCampYear', undefined);
  Session.set('keyDonate', donateTemp);
  }
});

Template.query.events({
  'click #camp-year-button': function() {
    var campYearTemp = document.getElementById('camp-year').value;
  Session.set('keyDonate', undefined);
  Session.set('keyCampYear', campYearTemp);
  }
});
```